# Can i create multiple schema in prisma for each model?

Tags: schema, prisma

This is a default structure of prisma schema...

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id Int  @id @default(autoincrement())
  username String @unique @db.VarChar(255)
  role UserRole @default(admin)
  posts Post[]
}

model Post {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  title String 
  post String @db.VarChar(500)
  created_at DateTime @default(now())
  updated_at DateTime @updatedAt
  user_id Int
  user User @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id])
}

//custom enums
enum UserRole {
  client
  admin
}
```

I want to create multiple schema for each models. User schema for user model, Post schema for post model. Like we use models in mongoose. Is it possible in Prisma ORM?

Comment: Related issue on prisma: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2377 , looks like it is not officially supported currently, but there are 3rd party workarounds like prisma-merge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Prisma hasn't introduced any solution for this matter yet, used this awesome package [Prismix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prismix) and solved the issue. Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Prisma `multiSchema` is now supported as a preview feature.

See here https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/multi-schema

It was introduced in version `4.3.0` https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/1122#issuecomment-1231773471

As the docs say you would add the preview feature...

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["multiSchema"]
}
```

Then in your `datasource` you note the schemas...

```
datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
  schemas  = ["User", "Post"]
}
```

And finally in each model you add the `@@schema` attribute...

```
model User {
  id Int  @id @default(autoincrement())
  username String @unique @db.VarChar(255)
  role UserRole @default(admin)
  posts Post[]

  @@schema("User")
}

model Post {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  title String 
  post String @db.VarChar(500)
  created_at DateTime @default(now())
  updated_at DateTime @updatedAt
  user_id Int
  user User @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id])

  @@schema("Post")
}
```

Note:

It might not be possible to do cross schema foreign keys. I saw it mentioned somewhere, but I can't find it now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,
You can use multiple schema using this : [Prisma-multischema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prisma-multischema)
.